# Haskell Yesod start project error

Tags: haskell, yesod, aeson

Install Yesod Web-framework. Initialize project, then start it. Get an error:

```
cabal: The following installed packages are broken because other packages they
depend on are missing. These broken packages must be rebuilt before they can
be used.
package persistent-1.1.5.1 is broken due to missing package
aeson-0.6.2.0-0b5b1be15e07744226b068e794d3d16c
package persistent-postgresql-1.1.3.1 is broken due to missing package
aeson-0.6.2.0-0b5b1be15e07744226b068e794d3d16c
package persistent-template-1.1.3.1 is broken due to missing package
aeson-0.6.2.0-0b5b1be15e07744226b068e794d3d16c
package shakespeare-js-1.1.4.1 is broken due to missing package
aeson-0.6.2.0-0b5b1be15e07744226b068e794d3d16c
package yaml-0.8.5 is broken due to missing package
aeson-0.6.2.0-0b5b1be15e07744226b068e794d3d16c
```

But the aeson-0.6.2 package already installed:

```
cabal install aeson-0.6.2
Resolving dependencies...
cabal: Could not resolve dependencies:
next goal: aeson (user goal)
rejecting: aeson-0.6.2.0/installed-353..., 0.6.2.0, 0.6.1.0/installed-23c...,
0.6.1.0, 0.6.0.2, 0.6.0.1, 0.6.0.0, 0.5.0.0, 0.4.0.1, 0.4.0.0, 0.3.2.14,
0.3.2.13, 0.3.2.12, 0.3.2.11, 0.3.2.10, 0.3.2.9, 0.3.2.8, 0.3.2.7, 0.3.2.6,
0.3.2.5, 0.3.2.4, 0.3.2.3, 0.3.2.2, 0.3.2.1, 0.3.2.0, 0.3.1.1, 0.3.1.0,
0.3.0.0, 0.2.0.0, 0.1.0.0 (global constraint requires ==0.6.2)
```

How to resolve this problem?

Comment: Have you tried `cabal update && cabal install`?

Comment: How did you "start it"?  If you're using `yesod devel` with the `cabal-dev` option (`--dev` I think?) it will be expecting a `cabal-dev` directory.  If you originally installed dependencies at a user level with cabal this probably won't work.

Comment: @lambdas - yeah, I have.

Comment: @AndrewMyers - as I understand, yesod devel start the development version of project. Isn't it use all dependencies that installed with cabal-dev package?

Comment: @Lsissomort `yesod devel` runs your project with a develop server which watches for file changes and recompiles/restarts the service.  If you want it to use cabal-dev you have to use the `--dev` option so `yesod devel --dev`.

Comment: When I tried yesod `devel --dev` I had no answer, terminal window stay clean and nothing happen.